# Is there a way to detect reflows instantly in Angular, without using $timeout?

Tags: html, angularjs, canvas, scrollbar, reflow

I'm working on a site with a scrollable list of canvases for plotting data, and I need to resize the canvases whenever the width of the div they're in changes.

I have it working in most cases, but if I delete a plot such that the scroll bar goes away, it doesn't work.  I tried the following, where plotsScroller is the div with the scroll bar and plotsList is what's inside of it:

```
    $scope.isScrollingPlotsList = function() {
        return plotsList.offsetHeight > plotsScroller.offsetHeight;
    }

    $scope.$watch('isScrollingPlotsList()', $scope.$apply);
```

This code would work *except* that no `$digest` happens after the reflow that removes the scroll bar; `$digest` is called when I delete a plot but I guess the reflow happens later.

Does anyone know how I can detect the reflow without using `$timeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in the DOM. When a change occur you will be notified and can traverse to see what changed.

An example of usage ([source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Also see the source link for details.

It should be supported in all major browsers incl. IE11. For [IE9, IE11> there exists a [polyfill](https://github.com/polymer/MutationObservers) that can be used.

[The specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutation-observers)

Comment: I hadn't heard of Mutation Observers, that would be great!  Now if only I could convince my boss to stop supporting IE < 11...

Comment: Added link to polyfill :-)

Comment: According to the site, "This uses MutationEvents to implement MutationObserves so you need at least IE9."